# Tkinter Calculator Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, calculator

I am trying to create a program in python 3.4.2 using tkinter. I hope to create a GUI calculator. So far i've been able to code out the buttons and layout (interface) of the program. The only thing that i need help with is the actions that the buttons perform. For example, i need a way to enter the value of the button pressed into my entry bar at the top of the calculator. (e,g: I press button 7 and 7 pops up into my entry bar). I need help coding that because i don't know how. So far my only working button on screen is the clear (ce) button as it clears the whole entry bar in my GUI. Can someone please take a look at my code below to help me establish a way to get this calculator working. (P.S i'm not no genius at tkinter, so basically try to explain it to me as you would to   to a 10 year old LOOL).

**Summary:**

1. Connect my buttons to my entry bar.

***My code:***

```
#Project Name : Calculator ++
#Version : 1.7.2
#Written by : Pamal Mangat.
#Start Date : Monday, July 7th, 2015.

import sys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def clear():
    txtDisplay.delete(0,END);
    return;

#Parent Window.
root = Tk();
root.title('Calculator ++ [1.7.2]');
root.geometry('350x450');

#Main entry.
num1 = StringVar();
txtDisplay = Entry(root, textvariable = num1, relief=RIDGE, bd = 10, width=33,    insertwidth = 1, font = 40);
txtDisplay.place(x=15, y=10);
txtDisplay.focus();

#Buttons:
zeroButton = Button(root, text='0', width=20, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=17,y=382);
oneButton = Button(root, text='1', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=17, y=302);
twoButton = Button(root, text='2', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=100, y=302);
threeButton = Button(root, text='3', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=182, y=302);
fourButton = Button(root, text='4', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=17, y=222);
fiveButton = Button(root, text='5', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=100, y=222);
sixButton = Button(root, text='6', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=182, y=222);
sevenButton = Button(root, text='7', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=17, y=142);
eightButton = Button(root, text='8', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=100, y=142);
ninthButton = Button(root, text='9', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=182, y=142);

decimalButton = Button(root, text='.', width=8, height=3, bg='powder blue').place(x=182, y=382);
equalButton = Button(root, text='=', width=8, height=8, bg='Lightgreen').place(x=264, y=307);
plusButton = Button(root, text='+', width=8, height=3, bg='gray').place(x=264, y=222);
minusButton = Button(root, text='-', width=8, height=3, bg='gray').place(x=264, y=142);
multiplyButton = Button(root, text='x', width=8, height=3, bg='gray').place(x=264, y=66);
divideButton = Button(root, text='÷', width=8, height=3, bg='gray').place(x=182, y=66);
clearButton = Button(root, text='Clear (CE)', width=20, height=3, command =      clear, bg='Orange').place(x=17, y=66);

#Locks the parent windows size.
root.maxsize(350,450);
root.minsize(350,450);

#Parent window's background color:
root.configure(background = 'black');
root.mainloop();
```

Below is an image of what my code executes and looks like once it's runned. The only issue is that it's just a bunch of pushable buttons with no use; except for clear(ce) which i happened to get running. The other buttons need meaning and a function, because i really want to get this program up and running.

[image: Calculator Image]

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation for the `Entry` widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.html).

Comment: Yeah i've read that link, but honestly i still need help with connecting my buttons to my entry(). Is there any way you know how?

Comment: That would be the `command` option, explained in the [documentation for the `Button` widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.html). Also, don't chain your geometry manager methods (viz: `place()`) onto the end of your widget construction, or the references all end up pointing to `None`, which is not useful.

Comment: Oh so i should put my .place() geometry methods on a different line, what do you mean, (points to none)? Also thanks for the help :)

Comment: I know this might be annoying but i don't see anything in that article referring to connecting buttons to entry() anywhere. I know i can use the command method to issue a command to the button and link it to a function or whatever, but how would i link that button straight to an entry, could you maybe show me a mini example or whatever? It would really help me out.

Comment: The linked function (called the "callback") would interact with the `Entry` widget using the methods listed in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ppl wrote in the comments, you need a function that will respond to button pressed and will update the Entry widget. I modified the code, to show how it can be done:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def clear():
    txtDisplay.delete(0,END);
    return;

#Parent Window.
root = Tk();
root.title('Calculator ++ [1.7.2]');
root.geometry('350x450');

#Main entry.
num1 = StringVar();
txtDisplay = Entry(root, textvariable = num1, relief=RIDGE, bd = 10, width=33,    insertwidth = 1, font = 40);
txtDisplay.place(x=15, y=10);
txtDisplay.focus();


def update_entry(v):
    current_value = num1.get()
    num1.set(current_value + v)

#Buttons:
zeroButton = Button(root, text='0', width=20, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command = lambda: update_entry('0')).place(x=17,y=382);
oneButton = Button(root, text='1', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red', command = lambda: update_entry('1')).place(x=17, y=302);
twoButton = Button(root, text='2', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=100, y=302);
threeButton = Button(root, text='3', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=182, y=302);
fourButton = Button(root, text='4', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=17, y=222);
fiveButton = Button(root, text='5', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=100, y=222);
sixButton = Button(root, text='6', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=182, y=222);
sevenButton = Button(root, text='7', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=17, y=142);
eightButton = Button(root, text='8', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=100, y=142);
ninthButton = Button(root, text='9', width=8, height=3, bg='LightBlue', fg='red').place(x=182, y=142);

decimalButton = Button(root, text='.', width=8, height=3, bg='powder blue').place(x=182, y=382);
equalButton = Button(root, text='=', width=8, height=8, bg='Lightgreen').place(x=264, y=307);
plusButton = Button(root, text='+', width=8, height=3, bg='gray', command = lambda: update_entry('+')).place(x=264, y=222);
minusButton = Button(root, text='-', width=8, height=3, bg='gray').place(x=264, y=142);
multiplyButton = Button(root, text='x', width=8, height=3, bg='gray').place(x=264, y=66);
divideButton = Button(root, text='÷', width=8, height=3, bg='gray').place(x=182, y=66);
clearButton = Button(root, text='Clear (CE)', width=20, height=3, command =      clear, bg='Orange').place(x=17, y=66);

#Locks the parent windows size.
root.maxsize(350,450);
root.minsize(350,450);

#Parent window's background color:
root.configure(background = 'black');
root.mainloop();
```

I added `update_entry` function that updates the Entry text variable. Also added lambdas to buttons 0 and 1 and + for an instration of use. Other buttons are not done. Also dont use place (or grid) in one line as you have now as all your Button variables will be None.

Comment: Okay i have update my code and i have placed my geometry methods (.place(x=#, y=#)) on a different line like requested and i have updated the function to run with all the buttons. Now the only thing that needs to be completed is the actual math portion of the program. Like how will i display the answer in the entry bar. I know how to do it with 4+4=8 but what if the user enters multiple numbers such as e,g :  2+2*6 . How would i display just the answer?